How correctly and effectively render replies to comments in FlatList
I`m making a news page where you can write comments and reply to them. I have all the logic done, but I don't know how to make the display of comments and replies correctly. I have comments rendered on the ViewLayout page using FlatList where I render comments CommentCard, and inside CommentCard I render replies when I click the button "View comments".
The whole problem is that when the list of answers opens, the screen flashes (the screen turns white for a second). I tried to fix it with animations, Accordion, Collapsible, but everything looked super awful (I'll attach a couple of examples). I don't deny that maybe I implemented it incorrectly, but I just don't know how to do it correctly: should the logic of displaying answers be transferred to ViewLayout or left in CommentCard? Can you please help with an example of how best to do this?
If it works out, then i wanna do it without reanimated.
Here`s my code (I shortened it a bit, but all the logic for displaying comments remains):
const ViewLayout = () => {
    const route = useRoute();
    const navigation = useNavigation();
    const { newsId} = route.params;
    const {user} = useGlobalContext();
    const { showAlert, alertData, showCustomAlert, hideCustomAlert } =useCustomAlert()
    const { newsData, comments, isLiked,  isLoading, setIsLiked} = useNewsData(newsId,user.uid)

....

  if(isLoading && !refreshing){
    return (<Loader isLoading={isLoading}/>) 
  }
  return (
    <SafeAreaView className="bg-white flex-1">
      <FlatList 
        data={comments}
        ref={flatListRef}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.$id}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <CommentCard
          commentId={item.$id}
          username={item.user_name}
          creatorLogin={item.user_login}
          date={item.date}
          text={item.text}
          likes={item.likes}
          comments={item.numComments}
          isLiked={item.isLiked}
          user={user}
          newsId={newsId}
          handleDelete={()=>handleDeleteComment(item.$id)}
        />
        )}
        ListHeaderComponent={() =>(
          <View className="w-full">
            {/*Шапка*/}
            <View className="bg-white pt-8 pb-2 px-4 flex-row justify-between border-b border-gray-200 shadow-md">
              <BackButton
                handlePress={()=>router.back()}
                className=""
                black
              />
              <View className="flex-row justify-between space-x-2 items-center">
                {(user.role=='ADMIN' || user.login==newsData.creatorLogin) &&
                  <EditButton 
                    handlePress={goToUpdatePage}
                    className="mr-auto  "
                    backgroundColor="bg-pink-200"
                  />
                }
                {newsData.link ? (
                  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => openLink(newsData.link)} 
                  >
                    <Image 
                      source={icons.globe}
                      className="w-[40px] h-[50px]  "
                      resizeMode='contain'
                    />
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                ) : null}
              </View>
            </View>

            {/*Новость*/}
            <View className="flex-1 border-b border-gray-200">
              <View className="px-5 pt-3 pb-2 flex-col justify-between space-y-4">

                <View className="flex-col justify-between space-y-2">
                  <View className="items-center">
                    <Image
                      source={{uri:newsData.imageUri}}
                      resizeMode='cover'
                      className="w-full h-[210px] rounded-md"
                    />
                  </View>
                <View className="flex-row items-start justify-between space-x-5">
                  <View className="mt-1 flex-row items-center justify-start space-x-3">
                    <Text className="text-sm font-msemibold text-primary-800">{newsData.theme}</Text>
                    <Text className="text-sm font-msemibold text-grey-600">•</Text>
                    <Text className="text-xs font-msemibold text-grey-600 mt-[2.9px]">{newsData.date}</Text>
                  </View>
                <View className="flex-row justify-between space-x-2">
                  <View className="flex-row justify-between space-x-1">
                    <TouchableOpacity
                      onPress={handleLikeToggle}
                      className="mt-[-1px]"
                    >
                      <Image
                        source={isLiked? icons.icon_like_pressed : icons.icon_like}
                        resizeMode='contain'
                        className="w-[23px] h-[23px]"
                      />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <Text className="text-sm font-msemibold text-grey-600 ">{newsData.likes}</Text>
                  </View>
                  <View className="flex-row justify-between space-x-[2px]">
                    <TouchableOpacity
                      className="mb-1"
                      onPress={scrollToComments}
                    >
                      <Image 
                        source={icons.icon_comment}
                        resizeMode='contain'
                        className="w-[25px] h-[20px]"
                      />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <Text className="text-sm font-msemibold text-grey-600 ">{newsData.numComments?newsData.numComments:'0'}</Text>
                  </View>
                </View>
              </View>
            </View>
          
            <View className="">
              <Text className="text-lg text-black-500 font-mextrabold">{newsData.title}</Text>
            </View>
            <View>
              <Text className="text-primary-800 text-sm font-msemibold">Автор</Text>
              <View className="mt-1 flex-row justify-start items-center">
                <Image
                  source={icons.creator_icon}
                  className="w-[25px] h-[25px]"
                  resizeMode='contain'
                />
                <Text className="text-grey-600 text-sm font-mmedium ml-2">{newsData.creatorName}</Text>
              </View>
            </View>
            <View>
              <Text className="text-primary-800 text-sm font-msemibold">Опис</Text>
              <Text className="text-sm text-grey-600 font-mmedium">{newsData.subtitle}</Text>
            </View>
            <View className="mb-4">
              <Text className="text-sm text-grey-600 font-mmedium">{newsData.text}</Text>
            </View>
          </View> 
      </View>
          {/* Коментарі */}
          <View className="flex-row px-5 pt-8 pb-5" 
                ref={commentRef} 
                onLayout={onCommentLayout}
          >
            <CommentField
              otherStyles=""
              placeholder="Напишіть коментар..."
              value={inputValue}
              handleChangeText={handleChangeText}
              onSend={handleSendComment}
            />
          </View>
      </View>
        )}
        refreshControl={
          <RefreshControl refreshing={refreshing} onRefresh={onRefresh} />
        }
        ListEmptyComponent={() => (
          <View className="pb-10">
            <EmptyState
              title="Коментарів немає"
              subtitle="Будь першим(-ою) хто опублікує коментар"
              textStyle="text-grey-600"
              comments
            />
          </View>
        )}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
      />

      {showAlert && (
                <CustomAlert
                    title={alertData.title}
                    text={alertData.message}
                    buttons={[{
                        title: 'Oк',
                        onPress: hideCustomAlert 
                    }]}
                    visible={showAlert}
                    onBackdropPress={hideCustomAlert}
                />
            )}
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
}

export default ViewLayout

CommentCard where i made logic for rendering replies:
import { View, Text,Image, TouchableOpacity, TextInput, LayoutAnimation, UIManager, Platform, Animated, ActivityIndicator} from 'react-native'
import React, { useState,useEffect,useRef } from 'react'
import { icons, images } from '../../constants'
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import CustomAlert from '../Custom Alerts/CustomAlert';
import * as Animatable from "react-native-animatable";
import Accordion from 'react-native-collapsible/Accordion';

if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
  UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental &&
    UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental(true);
}

const CommentCard = ({
  commentId,
  newsId,
  image,
  username,
  creatorLogin,
  date,
  text,
  likes,
  comments,
  commentsArray,
  user,
  handleDelete,
  handleEdit,
  isLiked
}) => {
  const { showAlert, alertData, showCustomAlert, hideCustomAlert } =useCustomAlert()
  const {replies,isLoading}=useCommentData(newsId,commentId,user.uid)
  const dateText = useDateDiffString(date);
  const [likedState, setLikedState]=useState(isLiked)

  const [updateNumComments, setNumComments]=useState(comments||0)
  const [isEditing, setIsEditing] = useState(false); 

  ... 
  const toggleReplies=async()=>{
    //LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.linear);
    setIsRepliesVisible(!isRepliesVisible)
  }
  const handleAnswering=()=>{
    //LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.linear);
    setIsAnswering(!isAnswering)
  }

  ....

// ---- Rendering replies
  const renderReplies=()=>{
    //LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.linear);
    return (
        <View className="pl-10 mt-2">
          {replies.map((reply) => (
            <ReplyCard
              key={reply.$id}
              replyId={reply.$id}
              commentId={commentId}
              newsId={newsId}
              user={user}
              username={reply.user_name}
              creatorLogin={reply.user_login}
              date={reply.date}
              text={reply.text}
              likes={reply.likes}
              comments={reply.numAnswers}
              handleDelete={() => {deleteReply(reply.$id)}}
              isLiked={reply.isLiked}
              handleAnswering={()=>handleAnswering()}
              onReplyAdded={() => {}}
            />
          ))}
        </View>
    );
  }
  const renderCommentField=()=>{
    return(
        <View className="pl-10 mt-2">
          <CommentField 
            otherStyles=""
            placeholder="Напишіть коментар..."
            contentStyle="w-auto"
            value={replyText}
            handleChangeText={(e)=>setReplyText(e)}
            onSend={sendReply}
          />
        </View>
    )
  }
  return (
    <View className={`px-5 pb-4 relative`}>
      <View className="px-3 py-4 flex-col justify-center items-start border border-grey-border rounded-xl bg-white">
        <View className="flex-row justify-between items-start w-full pb-3">
          <View className="flex-row justify-between items-center">
            <Image
              source={images.avatar}
              resizeMode="contain"
              className="w-[40px] h-[40px] rounded-full"
            />
            <View className="flex-col justify-start items-start ml-2">
              <Text className="text-xs font-msemibold text-black-500">{username}</Text>
              <Text className="text-xs font-mlight text-black-500">{dateText}</Text>
            </View>
          </View>

          <View className="flex-row items-center space-x-1">
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={handleLikeToggle}
            >
              <Icon 
                  name={likedState ? "heart" : "heart-o"} 
                  size={18} 
                  color={likedState ? "#F95757" : "#4E4E4E"}  
              />
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <Text className="text-xs font-msemibold text-black-500">{likes}</Text>
            {(user.login===creatorLogin || user.role==='ADMIN')&&(
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={toggleDropdown}>
              <Image
                source={icons.dots_vertical}
                className="w-[21px] h-[24px] mt-[-2px]"
                resizeMode="contain"
              />
            </TouchableOpacity>
            )}
          </View>
        </View>
        
        {isEditing ? (
                  <View className="w-full mt-2">
                      <TextInput
                          value={editedText}
                          onChangeText={setEditedText}
                          multiline={true}
                          className="text-sm font-mmedium text-black-500 text-left border border-grey-border p-2 rounded w-full"
                      />
                      <View className="flex-row justify-between items-center mt-4 w-full">
                          <SmallOutlinedButton
                              containerStyles="border-primary-default min-h-[21px]"
                              textStyles="text-grey-400"
                              title="Скасувати"
                              handlePress={() => {
                                  setIsEditing(false);
                                  setEditedText(text);
                              }}
                          />
                          <SmallOutlinedButton
                              containerStyles="border-primary-default min-h-[21px]"
                              textStyles="text-grey-400"
                              title="Зберегти"
                              handlePress={handleUpdateComment}
                          />
                      </View>
                  </View>
              ) : (
                  <>
                      <Text className="text-sm font-mmedium text-black-500 text-left">{text}</Text>
                      
                      <View className="mt-3 flex-row items-center w-full justify-between">
                      <View className="flex-1 flex-row justify-start">
                          {updateNumComments > 0 && (
                              <SmallOutlinedButton
                                  containerStyles="border-primary-default min-h-[21px]"
                                  textStyles="text-grey-400"
                                  image={icons.arrow_down}
                                  imageStyles="w-[14px] h-[14px]"
                                  imageContainer="pr-2"
                                  title={isRepliesVisible ? "Сховати відповіді" : `${updateNumComments} відповіді`}
                                  handlePress={toggleReplies}
                              />
                          )}
                          </View>
                          {updateNumComments === 0 && <View className="flex-grow" />}

                          <SmallOutlinedButton
                              containerStyles="border-primary-default min-h-[21px]"
                              textStyles="text-grey-400"
                              title="Відповісти"
                              handlePress={handleAnswering}
                          />
                      </View>
                  </>
              )}
        
        {/* Выпадающее меню */}
        {isOpen && (
              <DropdownMenu
                  isVisible={isOpen}
                  handleDelete={handleDelete}
                  isEditing={isEditing}
                  handleEdit={handleEditComment}
                  toggleDropdown={toggleDropdown}
              />
          )}
      
    
  </View>
  {isAnswering && renderCommentField()} 
    
  {isRepliesVisible && renderReplies()} // ---- Rendering replies

  {showAlert && (
    <CustomAlert
      title={alertData.title}
      text={alertData.message}
      buttons={[{
        title: 'Oк',
        onPress: hideCustomAlert 
      }]}
      visible={showAlert}
      onBackdropPress={hideCustomAlert}
    />
  )}
  </View>
  );
};

export { CommentCard };

Now it looks like that:
Now gif
When i was using LayoutAnimation gif


the screen turns white for a second

Probably you could investigate this
  if(isLoading && !refreshing){
    return (
      <SafeAreaView className="bg-white flex-1 items-center"> <---- add this 
        <Loader isLoading={isLoading}/>)   

  }
  return (
    <SafeAreaView className="bg-white flex-1">
      ...


because it looks like you are using tanstack-query to fetch the data and the initial render is the <Loader />

Hi! Thanks for your reply. I tried to remove the if(isLoading && !refreshing) block and add SafeAreaView to there, but it didn't make any difference. But I realized that the color of the flickering when clicking on the answers depends on the "main" SafeAreaView ^^
